# PubNub Broadcasting Geolocation, XHR failed loading: GET

Tags: angularjs, geolocation, pubnub

I am trying to make form from this source file workable:
https://gist.github.com/AnatoliYatskevich/cb1efe7f0f504f112fe3b3fe922fbe98

Steps were done:

1. Amend file pasting pub, sub, uuid and channel keys
2. Created pubnub keyset and module. (At the moment there are
   only channel, Before publish or Fire and debug option set.)
3. Started https://gist.github.com/AnatoliYatskevich/cb1efe7f0f504f112fe3b3fe922fbe98 on localhost using WebStorm filled inputs and press Start
4. In browser console on localhost, I see the following message:

   > pubnub.min.js:60 XHR failed loading: GET"https://ps3.pubnub.com/publish/SUBKEY/PUBKEY/UUID"

   and hence failed publish>ngPublish
5. In PubNub https://admin.pubnub.com/#/user/ADDRESS console of my module I see no data output, however expect this.

**What should I change to publish locations?**

Additionally:

```
angular.module('broadcastApp', ["pubnub.angular.service"])
  .controller('BcCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, PubNub, $window) {
    if (!$rootScope.initialized) {
      PubNub.init({
        subscribe_key: 'PUBKEY',
        publish_key: 'SUBKEY',
        uuid: 'UUID'
      });
      console.log(PubNub.subscribe_key);     //debug
      console.log(PubNub.publish_key);       //debug
      console.log(PubNub.uuid);              //debug
      $rootScope.initialized = true;
    }
...
}
```

Console output returns undefined exactly after PubNub.init and it's looks like a critical point which causes all the others.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Anatoli, you are possibly on a much older version of PubNub SDK. Can you please upgrade to a newer version of your choice from https://www.pubnub.com/docs and try again?

Comment: Hi Paras, I just try to use pubnub.4.19.0.min.js instead of pubnub.min.js and pubnub-angular-4.2.0.js instead of pubnub-angular.js but received this error "angular.js:11500 Error: [$injector:unpr]". It seems like additional investigation required from my side. Thanks for help